# Ultrafilters: normality implying $\kappa$-completeness?

Tags: set-theory, filters, large-cardinals

In Kanamori's *The Higher Infinite*, it's noted at least twice (just before 17.6, and at the beginning of section 19) that if
$$\langle M,\in,U\rangle\models U\text{ is a normal ultrafilter over }\kappa$$
then $U$ is $\kappa$-complete from $M$'s perspective.  (Here $M$ is some transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}-\mathsf{Powerset}$, and $\kappa$ is a cardinal of $M$.)

I'm just having trouble seeing why normality would imply $\kappa$-completeness here (I don't believe it does in general), and would appreciate any help in understanding this.  Perhaps I'm missing some assumptions or something.

Explicitly, just before 17.6, it's written

> For $N$ an inner model,
>
> > $W$ is an *$N$-normal ultrafilter over $\kappa$ iff*
> >     $\hspace{1em}$ (i) $W$ is an ultrafilter *on $\mathcal{P}(\kappa)\cap N$*, and
> >     $\hspace{1em}$ (ii)  for any $f\in {}^\kappa \kappa \cap N$ with $\{\xi<\kappa:f(\xi)<\xi\}\in W$
> >     $\hspace{1em}\phantom{(ii)}$ there is an $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $\{\xi<\kappa:f(\xi)=\alpha\}\in W$.
>
> Note that (ii) *subsumes what would be called $N$-$\kappa$-completeness*.

Referencing this, at the beginning of section 19, Kanamori writes

> Suppose that $M$ is a transitive $\in$-model of $\mathrm{ZFC}^-$; i.e. $\mathrm{ZFC}$ with the Power Set Axiom deleted.  Suppose also that $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal in the sense of $M$... Then
>
> > $U$ is an *$M$-ultrafilter over $\kappa$ iff*
> >     $\hspace{1em}$ (i) $\langle M,\in,U\rangle\models U\text{ is a normal ultrafilter over }\kappa$; and
> >     $\hspace{1em}$ (ii) $\langle M, U\rangle$ is weakly amenable: for any $F\in {}^\kappa M\cap M$, $\{\xi<\kappa:F(\xi)\in U\}\in M$
>
> An equivalent formulation of (i) was used for a definition before 17.6, and as noted there, *normality subsumes $\kappa$-completeness in the sense of $M$, and $U\in M$ is not required*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true without additional hypotheses.  For instance, if for some $\lambda<\kappa$ you have a normal $\lambda$-complete ultrafilter $W$ on $\lambda$, then $W$ generates an ultrafilter $U$ on $\kappa$ which will still be normal but is not $\kappa$-complete.

It is true if you additionally assume that every element of $U$ is unbounded.  To prove it, let $\lambda<\kappa$ and let $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}\in M$ be a sequence of subsets of $\kappa$ that are not in $U$; we must show that the union $A=\bigcup A_\alpha$ is also not in $U$.  Define $f:\kappa\to\kappa$ by letting $f(\xi)$ be the least $\alpha$ such that $\xi\in A_\alpha$ if $\xi\in A$, and $f(\xi)=\lambda$ otherwise.  Then $f(\xi)\leq\lambda$ for all $\xi$, and so $\{\xi<\kappa:f(\xi)<\xi\}$ is cobounded and thus in $U$.  By normality, there is thus some $\alpha$ such that $\{\xi<\kappa:f(\xi)=\alpha\}\in U$.  But if $\alpha<\lambda$ then $\{\xi<\kappa:f(\xi)=\alpha\}\subseteq A_\alpha$ and thus is not in $U$.  We must thus have $\alpha=\lambda$ so $\{\xi<\kappa:f(\xi)=\lambda\}=\kappa\setminus A\in U$, as desired.